# Change the Samsung's "Quick Settings" background color Or Remove Quick Settings

Tags: samsung, themes, background-process, quick-settings, samsung-galaxy-core-2

I have **Samsung galaxy core 2** Phone. I just want to change the background color (*The Dull Blue Colored one*) of the quick settings tab. I tried it by using **[Wanam Xposed](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/app-wanam-xposed-customize-stock-t2383484)**. It has many options, but I can't change the Quick Settings background color using it.

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 3):

Open *Wanam Xposed.* 
Go to *Theme* → *Background Color* → You may give *any HEX* value..

Also Go to *Theme*  → *Panel Background* → You may give *any HEX* value OR [Transparent Panel Background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqJA8.jpg).

Also Change *theme* → *Tile Pressed Color* (scroll down to last ).

---

Related subreddit - [Some modding I did with my S5, thought I'd share with y'all](https://www.reddit.com/r/galaxys5/comments/2dcsnq/some_modding_i_did_with_my_s5_thought_id_share_with_yall/cjocs29)

---

Bonus: Install [Bluured UI](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=58859218&postcount=1807) - icons color on notification panel might not change on Galaxy Core 2